# Is there a quantitative finance ranking system for universities?

Tags: research

I am a PhD student in stochastic analysis/control and had a MSc degree in Financial Mathematics.

I am interested in determining there is a quantitative finance ranking system for universities like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QS_World_University_Rankings). It's easy to find such a ranking for the Math Universities, though it doesn't hold for the quantitative/financial mathematics field.

Does such a ranking system exist, or is there another ranking system that can be applied to universities and quantitative finance -- and if so, how?

Comment: We will see how the community responds to your rephrasing, but this is likely a better question for advisor (you said you were a PhD student, correct?). Even if someone finds a ranking system, I would take it with a large grain of salt. Rankings for UG/MBA programs work because they have huge numbers of applicants and graduates (and graduates only care about USN&WR rankings), but when it comes to PhD and beyond, it is probably best to know the research and meet the researchers, then make a more subjective decision.

Comment: @richardh: sure, that was the first my idea - but my adviser is not working in the area of finance. I can say, that MIT, ETH Zurich, Cambridge, Oxford, Princeton, Berkeley and Stanford are famous math schools  and it's worth to make a PhD/PostDoc there in math. You can also see them in the top of any ranking list for mathematical universities. I just surprised that there is now such a confidence about the mathematical finance.

Comment: Btw, to those who downvote. Don't you want to clarify why are you downvoting. If the reason in off-topic, then maybe you can be also more precise, where is the off-topic? It will be useful not only for me to understand the opinion of community, but hopefully also for other people in the case they would like to ask a question on topic/offtopic boundary.

Comment: I agree with @Gortaur, it would be useful and also very interesting to share our thoughts on this topic.

Comment: I believe the question has changed significantly for the better.  The previous iteration of the question was highly subjective and barely readable.  Furthermore, post-Docs in finance are extremely rare in the US, so the question also became a bit impossible to answer.  However, ranking universities based on how well all their graduate degree programs (including masters) perform in teaching quantitative finance should be possible, though I haven't seen such a ranking done well.

Comment: @sheegaon: +1. Btw, don't you think that the comment *post-Docs in finance are extremely rare in the US* is a part of answer, not the absence of answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard of a ranking of post-doc programs in any academic field, but I guess the closest proxy would be a ranking of graduate schools. QuantNet has a [ranking of MFE programs](http://www.quantnet.com/mfe-programs-rankings/) in America, which is similar to the *US News and World Report* methodology.

Comment: that's interesting and quite expecting. I'll try to find the worldwide/Europe ranking .

Answer (score 6):

A different point of view: [The Top 10 Quant Schools, According to the Street](http://www.advancedtrading.com/articles/209102204) I personally like a survey whose board members have no other incentives and conflicting interests with the schools they evaluate.

Answer (score 5):

Just saw this question and would like to bring to attention that QuantNet has released its 2011 ranking of MFE programs in North America

http://www.quantnet.com/mfe-programs-rankings/

Full disclosure: I run QuantNet.

Comment: Andy, since *you* run quantnet, you should put a disclaimer in your answer.

Comment: Fair point. I thought it is obvious because I have the site url in my public profile here and past posts are clearly show that. Nonetheless, I add a disclaimer in the spirit of full disclosure.

Comment: Andy, thanks for fixing that. It is obvious to me, but most people don't check profiles. Also, from the FAQ: *Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you **must disclose** your affiliation in your answers.*

Answer (score 5):

http://www.mines-paristech.fr/Actualites/PR/EMP-ranking.html

Comment: Interesting ranking system. I'd like to see the same methodology employed using top hedge fund managers or top quant hedge fund managers.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken as of December 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea of the methodology, and it is not specifically quant, but here is another ranking from 2011: http://rankings.ft.com/businessschoolrankings/masters-in-finance-pre-experience-2011

Answer (score 2):

Risk Magazine publishes a **Quant Finance Master's Guide** every year which includes universities from the US, Europe and Asia. See [here](https://www.risk.net/quant-masters-2022) 2022's ranking with top-5 displayed below:

> 1. Princeton University (US), Master in Finance
> 2. Baruch College, CUNY (US), Master of Science in Financial Engineering
> 3. University of California Berkeley (US), Master of Financial Engineering
> 4. Paris Sorbonne/Polytechnique (France), Master in Probability and Finance
> 5. Imperial College London (UK), Master of Science in Mathematics and Finance

Comment: Thanks for keeping this alive an up to date! As well as posting an answer on my bday, a very nice present

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is some research on it, take for example

The Ten Commandments for Ranking University Quality by Michael McAleer

http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=785441

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of this? There is no abstract available. I also can't seem to download the paper without paying for it.

Comment: The paper is a guideline for the determinants of the quality of an university. Those are:
1. Mission statement; 2, Appointing and retaining high-quality staff; 3. size does matter; 4. balance between research and teaching; 5. importance research centres and research staff; 6. rank research output and quality using objective criteria; 7. objective indicators teaching quality; 8. quality undergraduate and graduate; 9. quality overseas; 10amount ridicule

Additionally it links some of the conclusions with the paper: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=886616 (which has an abstract)

Comment: Ok, the contents of your comment should be your **answer**. Don't put that in the comment; edit your **answer** to contain that info. It is of no value to anyone to have a link to a pay article and a missing abstract as your answer. I advise you to read some of the other posts on Stack Exchange to see what good content looks like.